# Eclipse 2019-09 R Cannot Install Tomcat 9

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Hi I tried to install tomcat9.0 on Eclipse but I got "unknown version of tomcat was specified" and the "next" button is dimmed. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: The _WTP Server Tools_ plugin supports Tomcat 9.0 since at least 2018. Can you explain how you tried to add the Tomcat 9.0 Server Runtime? Did you download the binary release from the official website? Which directory did you indicate as _"Tomcat installation directory"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Tomcat 9 is not the only version that explicitly supports Java 8**: If you check this [page,](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) you will see that "Supports Java version: 8 and later", which in this context means, that it officially supports only Java 8 and above. It does not mean however this is the only one supporting Java 8. Theoretically, you should be able to use any Tomcat version, in practice a.
- **Tomcat 8 will work perfectly**: well since it supports Java 7 and above. The majority of people with a Java8 + Tomcat combination are using Tomcat 8. Tomcat 8 also has Eclipse WTP support.

Comment: Dear Nishant, As I am under 15 reputations, I could comment "Vote +" for you. Thanks,

Comment: _"The majority of people with a Java8 + Tomcat combination are using Tomcat 8"_ - can you support it with some data or is it a personal opinion?

Comment: Dear Piotr , Thanks for helpful comment. I was asked to install the latest version. My current version is Java1.7+Tomcat7.0. Thus, I got no experience with higher Tomcat version. Thanks,